# Происхождение слова "крамола"

Tags: этимология

Значение  и происхождение слова "крамола"?

Answer (score 2):

Слово "крамола" общеславянское. Есть древнерусское слово "кромола". Во всех славянских языках слово несет тот смысл, что и в русском. А вот происходит оно, скорее всего, от латинского carmula, которое в свою очередь имеет то ли германское, то ли саксонское происхождение.